# C# Dictionary with dynamic type as Value

Tags: c#, dictionary

Here's the thing, I don't know for sure which value I will add to my Dictionary, therefore I need the value field to be dynamic. The key is always a string though.

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> data = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>;
```

Now If I loop through my form controls I'm able to do the following:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if(c is TextBox)
      data.Add(c.Name, c.Text);

   if(c is Checkbox)
      data.Add(c.Name, ((Checkbox)c).Checked);
}
```

I know that there's a key in my dictionary called `textBox1`, so how do I allow this kind of comparison?

```
if(data["textBox1"] == "something")
```

I receive the error:

> One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be
>   found. Are you missing a reference?

Comment: The reason `this.Controls` works is that `TextBox` and `Checkbox` both descend from `Control`. So if you have a base class or interface all of your values will adhere to, you can use that...

Comment: So you want to be able to compare a string to both strings and bools? How is that going to work? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: do you have `Microsoft.CSharp` referenced?

Comment: See also this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/24440745/215552 The question is almost a duplicate of this one...

Comment: @itsme86 yes, thats the goal. Although this is WinForms I'm trying to send from my View to my Controller all the data within the form, without pointing out key by key. I grab only the controls that matter.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I don't see any comparison in that link.

Comment: @DanielA.White was my first though..but yeah, otherwise I wouldn't be able to code in C#

Comment: In the general sense, I am able to get this to work without issue.  See [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZimNHJ).

Comment: @Linesofcode you can certainly use c# without that reference. that reference is needed for `dynamic`.

Comment: @DanielA.White should I delete this post? - that solved

Comment: @Linesofcode Generally it's suggested to leave these questions open to act as signposts to the original answer.

Comment: @itsme86, ok thanks.